# Of what use is the Heavy dropping a sandwich?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

Recently I've accidentally discovered that you can Right-Click to drop a sandwich (Heavy's 2nd weapon), but then I can't pick it up again.

Anyone know what's the point of dropping the sandwich apart from seeing teammate cluelessly gathering around it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the best feature of the Sandvich!

It works exactly like a health pack. It's great to be able to give a Medic your Sandwich, since he does not have a quick way to self heal.

The Sandvich will regenerate after a cooldown, or can be instantly recharged by visiting a Resupply cabinet, picking up your own thrown Sandvich, or collecting any health pickup while at full health.

Do note that you cannot replenish health by dropping your own Sandvich and walking over it, you will simply pick it up again. You *can* however pick up another Heavy's dropped Sandvich, which will restore health as per normal.

Just be careful the enemy can't get to it first: It can also heal them.

Comment: Thanks just tried it. 
Also noticed pushing the cart (which restore hp) will not regenerate the sandwich.

Comment: Heavies who don't throw the sandvich to their burning medic are **NOT** credit to team!